# How to handle failure in jenkins in a scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins

I want to write a scripted pipeline that if there is an error some steps needs to be followed.

Example :

try {
push to develop branch using git
}
catch (any){
raise pr to develop
}

in this case catch is not working if there is an error while pushing it to develop , ie push to develop is rehected. How to handle failures/errors in the pipeline ?

> Finally is working but catch is not working if push yo develop is rejected in git

Comment: Are you sure it's failing within the `try` block and not on a prior step?

Comment: Yes it's within try , but its an error not exception

Comment: Just catch Error and not Exception... `catch(Error e)`